# Is there a Ruby method that returns the last deleted element in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This might sound kind of weird, because if you delete an element from some_array, it presumably disappears from memory.
But in some cases it would be good to get the last item that was deleted, e.g. when keeping track of the last user someone unfollowed (i.e. deleted from their following array) and rendering a message like 'Bob has stopped following Smith' in the view. I'm not sure what method would accomplish that though, hence the question.

Edit: Storing the item in an instance variable before deleting wouldn't help I think, because instance variables only exist in a single controller action.

Here are some code snippets using the public_activity gem:

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
   # allow user to follow other users
   has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "follower_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy
  def unfollow(other_user)
    following.delete(other_user)
  end

end

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) {controller && controller.current_user}

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end

class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    flash[:notice] = "You've stopped following #{user.name}"
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

I want my activities/index path to render a _destroy partial that will say user x stopped following user y', along the following lines:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

and in the view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= link_to  activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
  <%= render_activity activity %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Instead of deleting user , why don't you try to take a Boolean field true or false to follow and unfollow to keep track to followed users?

Comment: Can you share a [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example illustrating your scenario?

Comment: What would happen if two unfollows occur in quick succession? I think it is a bad idea to track what happened *after* the deletion. You should rather try to catch the moment of deletion and do things right *before* the deletion happens.

Comment: You're wanting to "return the last deleted element in an array" *across requests*?

Comment: I added some code now to give more context to the question.

Comment: As @Gabbar suggested, soft deleting follows seems like the way to go. You can use something like the [discard gem](https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard) (or use it as a guide for your own implementation).

Comment: Why tag `ruby-on-rails-3.2` and `ruby-on-rails-4` both?

Comment: Your index view doesn't contain any partial (\_destroy) as of now.

Comment: In `User#unfollow`, where does `following` come from? You don't have it defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an auditing gem.

Try out

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

or

https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail

Answer (score 0):

I can't think in a method that deletes the last element and don't return it...
If you do: 
`var = ary.pop` will remove the last element and return it and you can save `var` in another table or whatever...
If you want a more robust solution you can search about papertrail gem.